# camel ftp2 file throw error when there is no file present in the folder

Tags: exception, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am working on reading the files from the sftp path and process the plain text files that are kept on the server every 5 hours. There is a requirement where I need to **throw an exception when there is no file present/kept on the server** by the producer. I am using the following to read the files

```
from(sftp://NUID@SERVER:PORT?&preferredAuthentications=password&delete=true)
            .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            .log("${body}")
            .process(processor)
            .end();
```

Now if there is no file present when the above route starts it doesn't say anything once there is a file on the server it consumes and process it. I want to throw an exception if there is no file present during a period of time.

Comment: which version of camel are you using? Try adding option `ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible way to throw an exception when there is no file present on the target server.

**1. Use sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle option** (from [file](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html))

Set this option to `true` will let your route receive an exchange with empty message when the polling consumer scan no file present on the target server. Then, you can add a new step in your route to throw exception when an empty message (but not normal exchange) is encountered.

**2. Setup another route with [timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) component to check last file processing time**

In your original route, add a new step to record the last file processing time in somewhere, then have a new route to periodically check whether difference between the last update time and current time is in acceptable time range.

Drawback: False alarm may occur from other problem (e.g. Continuous Network Issue)

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception that you receive called?

I checked the docu http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html and it may be caused due to an option not being set to true.
Please try again with `ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true` and also check the docu for other options that may apply.